# lag a field in a df by one day in corresponding date field

Tags: r

There are references to lag() in r with a time series or zoo object. I just have a dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(ymd('2021-01-01'), ymd('2021-01-31'), by = 1),
  x = 1:31
)

df %>% glimpse
Rows: 31
Columns: 2
$ date <date> 2021-01-01, 2021-01-02, 2021-01-03, 2021-01-04, 2021-01-05, 2021-01-06, 2021-01-07, 2021-01-08, 2021-01-09, …
$ x    <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30…
```

I would like a new column, y, which is the value of x on the preceding day. Example, for 2021-01-10 x=10, I would like y to be what x was on 2021-01-09 which here is 9.

How can I lag a data frame based on a date field?

Comment: `stats::lag` (the default in base R) is not what you need, perhaps you want `dplyr::lag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'date' are ordered, then we can just use `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(y = lag(x))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does this require that the df is sorted first? I can do that, but 'real life' is there a way where the logic is determined from the date field as opposed to the row?

Comment: @DougFir you can add `arrange` before creating the `lag` column (in case not sorted)

Answer (score 1):

In base `R` if the dataframe is ordered and assuming you don't want something like `NA` if a day is missing:

```
df$y <- c(NA, df$x[-nrow(df)])
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a nice answer too and it was a hard choice there